# powershell.exe : Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable

Tags: json, powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am reading a json response in jenkinsfile and then I am passing it to a stage which is creating a test cycle by reading the version id from the json response. I have tried many different way to pass the parameter but it is always showing me error 406. I have stored the versionId in baseid variable. if I do echo baseid then it works but how can I use it inside a powershell script as shown below. please help.

check **versionid** inside adding test cycle stage.

```
def config = "Release"
node {
                            def vid = readJSON file: 'E:/Jenkins/workspace/27-investigate-process/script.json'
                            baseid = "${vid.id}"
                            
                            echo baseid
                            
}

pipeline 
{
 agent none

parameters {
    string(name: 'SPRINT_NUMBER', defaultValue: '9959')
    string(name: 'RELEASE_NUMBER', defaultValue: '60')
    string(name: 'CYCLE_NAME', defaultValue: '60')
}

stages 
{
    stage('Windows')
            {
                agent 
                {
                    node 
                    {
                        label "csharp.is.avb.com"
                        customWorkspace "E:/Jenkins/ws/${env.BRANCH_NAME}".take(30)
                    }
                
                }
                stages 
                {
                    stage("Adding Test Cycle") 
                    {
                        steps 
                        {   
                            echo baseid 
                            powershell label: '', script: '''$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
                            $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            $headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic E6WnlreEA5NDA5NTAyMzIy")
                            $headers.Add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=D2C7FAFF013B856E8803F; atlassian.xsrf.token=B5DX-9S26-JQRI-OYXfd11236e12a575063_lin; sto-id=BHM")

                            $body = "{
                            `n  `"clonedCycleId`": `"`",
                            `n  `"name`": `"Official-${env:CYCLE_NAME}`",
                            `n  `"build`": `"`",
                            `n  `"environment`": `"`",
                            `n  `"description`": `"Create cycle with sprint`",
                            `n  `"startDate`": `"4/Dec/19`",
                            `n  `"endDate`": `"30/Dec/20`",
                            `n  `"projectId`": `"128`",
                            `n  `"versionId`": `"$baseid`"
                            `n}"

                            $response = Invoke-RestMethod \'https://jira.it.avb.com/rest/zapi/latest/cycle\' -Method \'POST\' -Headers $headers -Body $body
                            $response | ConvertTo-Json'''
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
   }
```

}

Comment: Did you have a look at the HttpRequest Plugin? It makes calling REST APIs a lot easier IMO

Comment: Yes i tried  but it didn't worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using script method. I created a environment variable and stored version id in it and then I used ${env:VID} wherever the version id is needed.

```
script 
    {
        env.VID = versionid
    }
```